# Complex SQL Table Relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem about database table and query of it. Let me tell what this is about. It is about project-manager-employee relationship. Now Let me tell in statements what their relationship...

**Manager** = Manager is a project leader or could be manager of MORE than ONE project.

**Employee** = (s)He is a person who only works on project or projectS which is managed by Manager.

**Project**= Project is a project which managed by only ONE Manager.

***Employee - Manager Relationship***

Manager is also a employee in company right? According to this I want their relationship like -> one Employee can be managed by more than ONE Manager.
All managers are in the same title  I mean there is no manager of a manager. There is only manager(s) for an employee. For example 5 employees can be managed by a Manager.

***Employee - Project Relationship***

Employee can have a project that make sense, also employee can have more than ONE project that's make sense too. So project can have more than ONE employee too. (reminder: Project can have more than ONE Employee, BUT can NOT be managed by more than ONE Manager).

***Manager - Project Relationship***

Manager can have more than ONE project. BUT Project can NOT be managed by more than ONE Manager.

***PS: According to project, same employee in different projects CAN BE managed by more than one manager See my example below...***

*Android App PROJECT's Manager*----> Patrick

*Android App PROJECT's Employees*-----> John, Susan, **Megan**, Joe.

Another Project...

*IOS App PROJECT's Manager*----> Ryan

*IOS App PROJECT's Employees*----> Claire, Walter, Robert, **Megan**

Now let me show my tables for that... I can't really know what should I do...

[image: Employee-Manager-Project current realationship]

In that table I tried to do that "manager_id(FK)" refer to "employee_id(PK)" because Manager is a employee in company.

And I have "manager_id(FK)" in Project table to refers "manager_id" in employee table.

And which is proj_employee table I didn't clearly understand. I found this way in examples from internet. That way we call them in query.

NOW let me post my queries I tried but never get a solution...

```
        select
    e.name as employee_name,
    pm.name as manager_name
from Proj_Employee as pe
    left outer join Employee as e on e.employee_id = pe.emp_id
    left outer join Project as p on p.project_id = pe.project_id
    left outer join Employee as pm on pm.employee_id = p.manager_id
where pe.project_id = <project id>
```

**I would like to ask this... I want a query which shows me EmployeeName, ManagerName OF choosen project. And if my table is wrong Could you guide me or tell me how can I do that?**

I have knowledge but couldn't figure it out how can I make this work.

Comment: What happens with your query?  Do you get an error?  Incorrect results?  No results?

Comment: Your query looks right to me, I don't see a problem with it. This looks EXACTLY how I would write the query (i'd exclude the unnecessary OUTER keyword, but that doesn't change anything.) Is the query returning incorrect results?  (I'm assuming manager_id in both the employee table and the project table are foreign keys to employee_id.)

Comment: manager_id in employee table refers employee_id in employee table...

manager_id in project table refers manager_id in employee table...

Comment: @Pitch: yes, I finally saw that (I guess I skimmed over it without really reading it, probably because you're using a different relationship in your query... your query does the join from p.manager_id = pm.employee_id, which is what we expect.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the problem (finally).

You said, "And I have "manager_id(FK)" in Project table to refers "manager_id" in employee table."

I think that may be the problem. I think you want `manager_id` in the `project` table to be a foreign key to the **`employee_id`** column in the `employee` table, NOT the **`manager_id`** column. But you've got it right in your query.

---

[SQL Fiddle demo here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e31fb/1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e31fb/1)

---

Not really related to your question, but I just want to take the opportunity to point out that this is a case where having the primary key column in each table named `id` helps us make "wrong" SQL look like "wrong" SQL. ["Making Wrong Code Look Wrong" - Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)

If we expect that:

primary keys will be of the form:  **`id`**

foreign keys will of the form:  **`parent_table_id`**, or **`parent_role_id`**

the vast majority of joins will be from foreign key to primary key

then we expect that most joins will be of the form

```
child.parent_id = parent.id
```

and that foreign key definitions will be of the form

```
FK_child_parent_or_role (parent_or_role_id) REFERENCES parent (id)
```

This makes a foreign key definition like this:

```
FK_project_manager (manager_id) REFERENCES employee (manager_id)
```

look "wrong" to us. We expect to see the reference to the `id` column.

Comment: I will post after trying.. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm Thats the thing i guess which is I did not insert values in proj_employee... My project is a web-project I try to get projecet-manager-employeesOfProject values from logged users info... And forward them to another page as a table... So this is process unrelated with that.. Why i told it? When a MANAGER insert a project to employees (assigns him to project) Where should i insert it in Database?? Thats the lifecycle of it... Where should i insert them? Added project also must be shown in Project table... Which way can I use? Thanks in advance.. really.

Comment: To add an employee to a project, insert a row to the proj_employee table. employee_id FK to employee(PK), project_id FK to project(PK).

Comment: I see. I should insert projects in proj_empp... How about deleting.. According to this I should delete from proj_emp. And If I want to add only project then I should add it to project table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of (project_name, manager_name, employee_name) with something like this:

```
SELECT p.project_name
     , e.name as employee_name
     , m.name as manager_name
FROM project p
INNER JOIN employee m ON p.manager_id = m.employee_id
LEFT JOIN proj_employee pe ON p.project_id = pe.project_id
LEFT JOIN employees e ON pe.emp_id = e.employee_id;
```

You will get something like this for two projects, one having no employees:

```
 project_name  | employee_name | manager_name 
---------------+---------------+--------------
 Stack O       | Alice         | Eve
 Stack O       | Bob           | Eve
 Lemon Squeezy |               | Alice
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to have outer joins that I can see.

```
select p.Project_Name, m.name as Manager, e.name as Employee
from Project P
join Employee M on m.employee_id = p.manager_id
join project_employee pe on pe.project_id = p.project_id
join Employee E on e.employee_id = pe.employee_id
```